# UISwitch status change overlap

Tags: ios, ios7, uiswitch

I have a problem with a `UISwitch` in a tableview cell.

This switch is normally in On position, then when a variable changes its value the switch go to the Off position but I have a problem like the switch in the second row:

[image]

This is the simple code into the cellForRowAtIndexPath section:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableView.opaque = NO;
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]]];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if ([self.title isEqualToString:@"Test"]) {cell.textLabel.text = [self.tester objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    if (([indexPath row] == 5) || ([indexPath row] == 4)){
        NSArray *segmentItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Down", @"Up", nil];
        UISegmentedControl *testSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentItems];
        testSegmentedControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        testSegmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
        testSegmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        testSegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(160, 10, 150, 30);
        [testSegmentedControl setTag:[indexPath row]];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:testSegmentedControl];
        [testSegmentedControl addTarget:self
                             action:@selector(testing:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
    else {
    mySwitch = [ [ UISwitch alloc ] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(200, 10, 0, 0) ];
    mySwitch.tag = [indexPath row];
    mySwitch.onTintColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        if ([indexPath row] == 0){
            if ([asd41 isEqualToString:@"False"]) mySwitch.on = NO;
            else mySwitch.on = YES;
        }
        if ([indexPath row] == 1){
            if ([asd40 isEqualToString:@"False"]) mySwitch.on = NO;
            else mySwitch.on = YES;
        }
        if ([indexPath row] == 2){
            if ([asd42 isEqualToString:@"False"]) mySwitch.on = NO;
            else mySwitch.on = YES;
        }
        if ([indexPath row] == 3){
            if ([asd76 isEqualToString:@"False"]) mySwitch.on = NO;
            else mySwitch.on = YES;
        }

    [ cell addSubview: mySwitch ];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.2];
        [mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switch1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];}

}
```

Comment: You are probably adding a switch over and over as the cell is reused. Only add a switch if you actually alloc/init the cell.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, you're right. In effect with                                     '[self.tableView reloadData];' I add a switch on another one. How can I update the switch status without reload all the tableview?

Comment: The problem isn't with calling `reloadData`. The problem is in `cellForRow...`. Only add a switch once per cell. Cells get reused. Don't add another switch for each reuse.

Comment: In my cellforrow.. I add only one switch, for each cell I used the code in the question.

Comment: Show your complete `cellForRow...` method in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank for the helps. The solution is in the question.

Comment: No. The solution is to only add the switch once. Your code will add an additional switch every time the cell is reused. Same for the segmented controls.

Comment: How can I add only one switch?

Comment: See if it has already been added to the cell first. Note the the cell could be reused for a different row so you need to update the tag if the cell is reused.